# Paramiko connection to Windows fails silently (appears to succeed)

Tags: python, powershell, paramiko, openssh

I am attempting to use paramiko to send powershell commands over ssh to a Windows box with OpenSSH on it. The commands appear to be successful (return code 0) even when they should fail, and I'm not getting any output on the pipes. When I try commands like making a directory, it is not created, which makes it seem as though the commands aren't reaching the remote system, but also aren't throwing errors.

First, here's my code:

```
version = self.oscall.run_remote(['java', '-version'])

def run_remote(self, command): # Command is a list of command + args
    string = ""
    self.timeout = 300
    for arg in command:
        string = string + " " + arg
    self.client.connect(self.host, username=self.user, password=self.pw, timeout=self.timeout)
    self.transport = self.client.get_transport()
    self.transport.set_keepalive(1)
    self.channel = self.transport.open_session(timeout=self.timeout) # transport is abstract connection, session is socket
    if self.channel.gettimeout() == None: self.channel.settimeout(self.timeout)
    self.channel.exec_command(string)
    self.out = self.channel.makefile()
    self.err = self.channel.makefile_stderr()
    self.output = CallOutput(self.out, self.err, None)
    self.output.returncode = self.channel.recv_exit_status()
    self.channel.close()
    return self.output

class CallOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, out, err, rc):
        self.out = out.readlines()
        self.err = err.readlines()
        self.outfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile() 
        for line in self.out:
            if isinstance(line, unicode): line = line.encode('utf-8')
            self.outfile.write(line + '\n')
        self.outfile.seek(0)
        self.errfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        for line in self.err:
            if isinstance(line, unicode): line = line.encode('utf-8')
            self.errfile.write(line + '\n')
        self.errfile.seek(0)
        self.returncode = rc
```

Sorry for the wall of text, but I went for completeness. This is part of a larger application.

This code works perfectly connecting to Linux, so I don't expect there to be many little bugs. The returncode is always 0, even for garbage, and there is never any output on the pipes. If I run the command just using the terminal, I get the correct output:

```
$ ssh testuser@testwin.internal.com 'java -version'
Warning: Permanently added 'testwin.internal.com,10.10.10.12' (ECDSA) to the 
list of known hosts.
testuser@testwin.internal.com's password:
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
$ echo $?
0
$ ssh testuser@testwin.internal.com 'foo'
foo : The term 'foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ foo
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (foo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

$ echo $?
1
```

The only difference between our Linux and Windows processes that I can think of is that on Windows we have to use a password, as we haven't setup passwordless ssh yet. What weird Windows idiosyncrasy am I missing? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it turns out to be way simpler than I was thinking.

```
string = ""
for arg in command:
    string = string + " " + arg
```

The above code produces " whatever command was passed in" and it turns out that Windows reacts extremely poorly to the preceding space, while linux didn't care. The new code snippet is:

```
string = ""
first = True
for arg in command:
    if first:
        string = string + arg
        first = False
    else:
        string = string + " " + arg
```

I'm leaving the title and details the same, to hopefully help anyone who makes the exact same error I did.